# Compare a dictionary to itself in Python

Tags: python

I'd like to compare a Python dictionary with itself. For example:

```
for key1 in d:
    for key2 in d:
        if key1 == key2:
            continue
        compare(d[key1],d[key2])
```

The above would work except I'm comparing key1 with key 2 and then later the reverse (key2 with key1).  The range of the second for-loop should really start after key1 to avoid repeated comparisons.  How can that be done?

Comment: Could we ask the use case please - it's just it seems a bit odd to do this...

Comment: @mgilson I guess I misread the code.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary -- No worries.  So did 4 other people apparently :)

Comment: @JonClements I think this is a common problem.  For example, say you have a dictionary of client names and you want to loop through to find pairs of clients that meet some criteria.  No reason to find that client A and B as well as B and A meet the criteria...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that [`itertools.combinations`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations) would be helpful here

```
>>> import itertools
>>> d = dict.fromkeys(range(5),0)
>>> list(itertools.combinations(d,2))
[(0, 1), (0, 2), (0, 3), (0, 4), (1, 2), (1, 3), (1, 4), (2, 3), (2, 4), (3, 4)]
```

so, for your case, you'd want:

```
for key1,key2 in itertools.combinations(d,2):
    compare(d[key1],d[key2])
```

Here's a silly example where I construct a list of pairs of people with brown eyes (or hair I suppose ...):

```
>>> d = dict.fromkeys(["Jon","Jane","Bob","Jim","Janice"],"blue")
>>> d["Jim"] = "Brown"
>>> d["Jane"] = "Brown"
>>> d["Bob"] = "Brown"
>>> [ (x,y) for (x,y) in itertools.combinations(d,2) if d[x]=="Brown" and d[y]=="Brown" ]
[('Jane', 'Bob'), ('Jane', 'Jim'), ('Bob', 'Jim')]
```

Comment: This worries me. What if the dictionary is large?

Comment: @jensph -- What's wrong with that?  My loop is done using `itertools`, it won't all be stored in memory at once.  (The only reason it is all stored in my first example is because I explicitly constructed a `list` from the iterable).  Of course, `itertools` needs to do some caching, but certainly no more than `N = len(d)` elements.

Comment: I assumed it'd need len(d)*len(d).  In any case, this worked nicely!

Answer (score 1):

Actually You don;t need the keys to deference the dictionary. As suggested by @mgilson, you can use the itertools.combinations to compare the values of the dictionaries directly

```
>>> from itertools import combinations
>>> d = {random.randint(1,100):i for i in range(10)}
>>> list(combinations(d.values(), 2))
[(7, 4), (7, 2), (7, 3), (7, 1), (7, 0), (7, 8), (7, 9), (7, 5), (7, 6), (4, 2), (4, 3), (4, 1), (4, 0), (4, 8), (4, 9), (4, 5), (4, 6), (2, 3), (2, 1), (2, 0), (2, 8), (2, 9), (2, 5), (2, 6), (3, 1), (3, 0), (3, 8), (3, 9), (3, 5), (3, 6), (1, 0), (1, 8), (1, 9), (1, 5), (1, 6), (0, 8), (0, 9), (0, 5), (0, 6), (8, 9), (8, 5), (8, 6), (9, 5), (9, 6), (5, 6)]
>>>
```

Comment: This is true -- As long as the keys aren't actually important.  It's a lot easier to go from keys -> values than the other way around :).

Answer (score 1):

To use `itertools.combinations` is obviously the best answer. But even the original code of the question needs just a tiny modification to do what it is expected to:

```
for key1 in d:
    for key2 in d:
        if key1 < key2:
            compare(d[key1],d[key2])
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to stick to a nested for-loop then the following does the trick:

```
d = dict(a=1,b=2,c=3,d=4)
k = d.keys()
l = len(k)

for i in range(l):
    for j in range(i+1,l):
        print d[k[i]] == d[k[j]]
```

Comment: Thanks. That does fit with what I was thinking.